# What happens if I delete the files from Desktop synced folder?

Tags: windows-7, onedrive, cloud

I am using windows 7 Desktop.

I want to delete files from my cloud storage. If i delete the unwanted files from desktop synced folder, Does it delete them from cloud or retains the files on cloud and deletes only the local version?

Comment: It depends of the solution, but normaly it will erase your files on the cloud too since it's synced.

Somes tools will allow you to unsync a specific folder on your local drive and keep it on the cloud (dropbox have an option for this).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you delete them from the synced folder they will disappear from the cloud.  I recently deleted 3GB using my PC and {after a while} they were no longer on OnDrive either from my PC or my phone.